# slide/toggle css

Tags: jquery, css, animation, toggle

is there any way to slide in and out a div from the left to right. the user must click on the "clickthis" to toggle.

example css:

```
.container{width:100px; position:absolute; left:-70px;}
.container .open{left:0px;}
.button{display:block; top:0px; right:0px; width:20px; height:20px;position:relative;
```

example HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="slide1">
    <div class="button" id="clickthis"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Check the examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `show()` and `hide()` to slide in and out your elements

eg:

```
$("<your-element>").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
```

and

```
$("<your-element>").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3103366/1370034) for more details.

You can have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) to learn to slide elements in different directions.

Comment: You can have a look at jQuery's `animate` property too. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (but you'll need jQuery):

```
$('#clickthis').click(function() {
    $('#slide1').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you click "clickthis", it will also hide when the div "slide1" is closed, right?

Well, if I understood yout question, to slide from the right to the left and close the div you should implement a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickthis').click(function() {
    $('#slide1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
  });
});
```

Anyway, there is a great tutorial for different slide effects: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery toggle function to slide in slide out:-

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $( "div" ).toggle( "slide", { direction: "left" }, "slow" );
});
```

For example please refer :- [Jquery Slide in/Slide out](http://jsfiddle.net/jigneshparmar/BzfnZ/)